# mounting remote using sshfs

Tags: mount, permissions, ssh

I'm trying to mount a remote server to edit some project i used to do that on windows using winscp. Now I'm using xubuntu and trying to mount a remote filesystem to my pc.

I'm using this command to do the things:

```
#useradd root fuse

#sshfs -o idmap=user,IdentityFile=/home/username/my_ssh_key user@www.remote-host.com:/ /mountpoint
```

Things work as i expected, the remote file system get mounted on my pc,
but I'm unable to edit and save a file in that remote directory, I got `permission denied` error when saving the file that i edited.

Does anyone know the workaround to this problem, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

`sshfs` uses `fuse` for permissions.

1. Add/Uncomment *user_allow_other* to **/etc/fuse.conf**
2. Add your user to the *fuse* group.

   - useradd -G fuse $USER
   - `reboot`
3. As your *normal user*, mount it

You should be able to `mount`/`unmount` with your normal user.  In some cases, you may have to `umount` as root, if the filesystem gets messed up, or you lose the link in a weird way.

Comment: `usermod -G` will overwrite the user's groups. Stick to `adduser $USER fuse` to avoid such silly problems.